# Python Quiz Scoring and Conditional Statement Problems

Tags: python

I've started learning Python at school for around a month now, and I have decided to make a quiz. I have added in a scoring system so if you were to answer a question incorrectly, it would tell you your score. However, this is not working and it always will give you a score of 0. Also, is there a way of only putting one else statement if they were to fail a question, instead of one for each question? Thanks :)

Here's an example of the code(Python 3.2.3):

```
#QUIZ


print("Welcome to the quiz")
print("Please choose a difficulty:")
difficulty = input("A) Hard   B)Easy")


if difficulty == "A":
    score = 0
    print("")
def question(score):
     print("You chose the hard difficulty")
     print("Where is the Great Victoria lake located?")
     answer1 = input("A) Canada   B)West Africa   C)Australia   D)North America")
     if answer1 == "C":
         print("Correct")
         score = score+1
     else:
         print("you failed the quiz")
         print("Score:",score)
         quit()





def question2(score):
     print("Who is most responsible for cracking the Enigma Code")
     answer2 = input("A) Alan Turing   B) Jeff Bezos   C) George Boole   D) Charles   Babbage")
     if answer2 == "A":
         print("Correct")
         score = score+1
     else: 
         print("you failed the quiz")
         print("Score:",score)
         quit()




def diff_easy(difficulty):
    if difficulty == "B":
        score2 = 0
        print("")


def question4(score2):
        print("You chose the easy difficulty")
        print("What is the capital of Australia?")
        answer1 = input("A) Canberra   B) Sydney   C)Melbourne")
        if answer1 == "A":
            print("Correct")
            score2 = score2+1
 else:
         print("you failed the quiz")
         print("Score:",score2)
         quit()


def question5(score2):
    print("When was the Great Fire of London?")
    answer2 = input("A) 1666   B) 1555   C)1605")
    if answer2 == "A":
         print("Correct")
         score2 = score2+1

    else:
         print("you failed the quiz")
         print("Score:",score2)
         quit()

if difficulty == "A":
    question(score)
    question2(score)



if difficulty == "B":
    diff_easy(difficulty)
    question4(score2)
    question5(score2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `score` variable you see inside your functions is a **copy** of the `score` variable you set, being passed *by value* (I *strongly* suggest you revise this topic). You need a way to pass the status around.

Soon you will discover objects, for now (and never more in the future!), a simple solution is making the `score` variable a global. Just replace

```
def question2(score):
```

with

```
def question2():
```

in **all** of your question functions and add `global score` as the first statement in each, like this:

```
def question5():
    global score
    print("When was the Great Fire of London?")
    answer2 = input("A) 1666   B) 1555   C)1605")
    if answer2 == "A":
         print("Correct")
         score = score + 1 
    else:
         print("you failed the quiz")
         print("Score:", score)
         quit()
```

Replace all the occurences of `score2` with `score` and you are done.

Of course you can use a single `if: else` branch for all questions. I will not give you the full solution, so that you can exercise, but here is a hint: make a function that will take three arguments:

1. the question
2. a list of possible answers
3. the correct answer

let's call this function `quiz`. Now you can use it like this:

```
quiz("When was the Great Fire of London?", ["1666", "1555", "1605"], "1666")
quiz("What is the capital of Australia?", ["Canberra", "Sydney", "Melbourne"], "Canberra")
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements like

```
   score2 = score2+1
```

in your code have no effect, because they modify a local variable.

For the other question: you should use a data structure to store questions and answers, so that you can iterate over them without repeating the same code many times.